# @Binds methods must have only one parameter whose type is assignable to the return type

Tags: java, android, dagger-2, dagger

I am migrating to the new dagger android 2.11

All set up based on the Google blueprint :MVP-Dagger.but I am having this error :

> Error:(22, 57) error: @Binds methods must have only one parameter
>   whose type is assignable to the return type

Here in this line :

```
   @ActivityScoped
    @Binds abstract PresenterFactory<MainContract.Presenter> providePresenterFactory(MainPresenter presenter);
```

The presenter :

```
@ActivityScoped
public class MainPresenter extends BasePresenterImpl<MainContract.View>
    implements MainContract.Presenter { public MainPresenter(String s) {..
} ... }
```

Someone have any idea on how to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Any specific reason why you try to bind `MainPresenter` to `PresenterFactory`?

Comment: It's just a n interface as a Factory that should be implemented to create a presenter for each feature

public interface PresenterFactory<T extends BasePresenter> {
  @NonNull T create();
}

Comment: So your presenter doesn't implement that interface, and it's not supposed to implement the interface, why do you try to bind it as an implementation to said interface?

Comment: Solution: don't try to `@Binds` a class to an interface that it does not implement

Comment: Yes ! @EpicPandaForce so I go with Provider , right?

Answer (score 22):

The error message explains everything:

> @Binds methods must have only one parameter whose type is assignable to the return type

Your `@Binds` method has a parameter of `MainPresenter`. This is not assignable to the return type `PresenterFactory<MainContract.Presenter>`. In other words, `MainPresenter` is not an instance of `PresenterFactory<MainContract.Presenter>`.

The correct syntax for `@Binds` methods is something like:

```
@Binds
abstract Abstraction bindAbstration(Concretion concretion)
```

where `concretion` is an instance of `Abstraction`.

Or, in Kotlin:

```
@Binds
abstract fun bindAbstraction(concretion: Concretion) : Abstraction
```

`@Binds` methods are not magic. They bind a type (for instance, an interface) and an implementation of that type *that Dagger knows how to provide* already.

*update*

You can convert your `@Provides` to `@Binds` with the following steps:

1. Make sure `MainPresenter` has an explicit constructor annotated with `@Inject` and that Dagger 2 can provide the dependencies in the constructor.
2. Write:

   ```
   @Binds
   abstract MainContract.Presenter bindPresenter(MainPresenter mainPresenter);
   ```

Comment: I see , the Provide one is work just fine. how can i convert it to Binds one ?  @ ActivityScoped @ Provides
    public PresenterFactory<MainContract.Presenter> providePresenterFactory(
        DataManager mDataManager) {
        return MainPresenter::new;
    }

FYI : PresenterFactory is an interface while the presenter it selft extends from BasePresenterImpl<MainContract.View>

Comment: Not working because the type of presenter instance is injected like this :   @Inject PresenterFactory<MainContract.Presenter> mPresenterFactory;

Comment: `abstract Abstraction bindAbstration(Concretion concretion)` this is the ultimate mantra to explain it.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same exception but in a different situation.

The exception was misleading for me. After adding

```
kapt {
 correctErrorTypes true 
}
```

to `build.gradle` I found the real problem:

```
error: [ComponentProcessor:MiscError] dagger.internal.codegen.ComponentProcessor was 
unable to process this class because not all of its dependencies could be resolved.
Check for compilation errors or a circular dependency with generated code.
```

and the hint `not all of its dependencies could be resolved` helped me to find out that I missed adding `implementation project(path: ':repository')` to `build.gradle` of my `app` module which handles DI stuff.

Hope this help others having same problem.

Answer (score -6):

Use @Provides instead of @Binds