# Android: "Build failed" error pointing to DI:dagger while building

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I'm getting the ""error: @Binds methods' parameter type must be assignable to the return type public abstract com.packagename.HomeRepository bindsHomeRepository(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()" in my build files while building my android project.

Comment: You didn't ask any question, nor did you provide any context on your classes and code used. I'm not sure what you expect, especially since the error message already tells you what's wrong and where. If it is unclear please explain what you're struggling with.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [@Binds methods must have only one parameter whose type is assignable to the return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46656117/binds-methods-must-have-only-one-parameter-whose-type-is-assignable-to-the-retu)

Answer (score 0):

example for Kotlin

```
@Module
abstract class HomeRepositoryModule {
    @Binds
    abstract fun bindHomeRepository(repository: HomeRepository): Repository <--- Check your return type
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> @Binds methods' parameter type must be assignable to the return type

It simply means that your HomeRepository is probably not of type "Repository".

Check that HomeRepository actually extends Repository:

```
class HomeRepository () : Repository {

}
```